# XML - Quoting Numerical Attributes

Tags: xml, syntax, standards, quotes

### Should numerical attributes in XML be quoted?

```
<root>
  <node size=45 />
  <foo bar=1.2>
    <baz foo=20>
  </foo>
</root>
```

vs.

```
<root>
  <node size="45" />
  <foo bar="1.2">
    <baz foo="20">
  </foo>
</root>
```

---

My code editor/browser seems fine without quotes, but most online resources seem to say they're required.

Comment: Just doing a quick google search, I think I would quote them.

Comment: Your code editor is probably in HTML mode rather than XML mode. XML requires quotes, always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp

> XML Attributes Must be Quoted

Attribute values must always be quoted. Either single or double quotes can be used. For         a person's sex, the person element can be written like this:

```
<person sex="female">
```

or like this:

```
<person sex='female'>
```

If the attribute value itself contains double quotes you can use single quotes, like in this example:

```
<gangster name='George "Shotgun" Ziegler'>
```

or you can use character entities:

```
<gangster name="George &quot;Shotgun&quot; Ziegler">
```

Updated to expand based on the newest comment, according the Microsoft universe at least.

[XElement.Value Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.value?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_Linq_XElement_Value)

```
public string Value { get; set; }
```

You can also see refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379256/is-xml-elements-attribute-value-always-data-type-of-string) as well

Comment: With some more digging, I found [this section of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-AttValue), specifying that every attribute must be quoted, as in this answer.

Comment: Is attribute treated always as string if it's quoted?

Comment: @s.paszko  I updated the answer accordingly, hope it helps.