# Is XML Elements Attribute value always data type of string?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement, xattribute

When I create a XML Document using LINQ, when I add some XElement to Root element with some Attributes and when I read that document`s XElement using LINQ, the returned value of XAttributes.Value is string by default!
In order to assign this value to bool type of variable, it is necessary to call function "Convert.ToBoolean()"

```
  XDocument Xd = new XDocument(new XElement("Numbers"));
  Xd.Root.Add(new XElement("13", new XAttribute("Name", "13")
                               , new XAttribute("IsEvenNumber", false)
                               , new XAttribute("HowManyDevidersItHas", 2)));
  Xd.Save(@"C:\XDocument.xml");
  bool b1 = Convert.ToBoolean(XD1.Root.Element("13").Attribute("IsEvenNumber").Value);
  ...
```

As you can see:
the value of XAttribute called "Name" must be as a long type!
the value of XAttribute called "IsEvenNumber" must be a bool type!

I need to know: Is it possible to create an XElement with some XAttributes, save it, read it again and assign its XAttributes.Value to some bool type variable without calling " Convert.ToBoolean()" function?!

Comment: You could create classes, with strongly typed members, and the serialize/deserialize the objects. The conversion will be automatically handled.

Comment: or without... casting: I mean without...                                       
bool b1 = (bool)(XD1.Root.Element("13").Attribute("IsEvenNumber").Value)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not, the `XElement.Value` property appears to be a string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value(v=vs.90).aspx

Thus you will always have to cast the value to your data type.